# How to check if file saved successfully in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

In my app i use the below code to wirte a .db file to Documents Directory and then want to use it

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                           NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                           NSLog(@"%@",str);

                           NSMutableDictionary *retval = [json  objectWithString:str];


                           if ([[retval objectForKey:@"Success"] boolValue])
                           {
                               NSString *downloadedData=[[retval objectForKey:@"Value"] objectForKey:@"SqLiteFileArray"];
                               NSData *mydata=[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString :downloadedData];

                               NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

                               NSString *documentDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

                               NSString *documentFile=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"4_program.db"];

                               NSString  * yourAppendingText=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:mydata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                               [yourAppendingText writeToFile:documentFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                               NSLog(@"finish");
                               //[self getfile];
                               //NSLog(@"data %@",downloadedData);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               NSLog(@"aaa");
                           }


                           self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;


                       }];
```

in nslog i see the finish statement so i thought the file written successfully

but when i re-enter to the app and check if file exists in documents directory it says it is not there

this is my file exists code:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSString *realpath;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

realpath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:
          [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"4_program.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: realpath ] == NO)
{

    NSLog(@"no file");


}
else
{
    NSLog(@"file found");
    [self getdata];

}
```

am i missing something? how can i learn file written successfully finished?

Comment: Your code does not confirm that the save path is the same as the path you're checking for existence at... are you certain they're identical?

Comment: yes both of them looking to documents directory and the filenames are same

Comment: NSLog both paths where they are used. See, there is an error in your assumptions because the code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

i changed to my writeToFile to

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentFile
                                contents:mydata
                                attributes:nil];
```

and now it works and everything is ok

Comment: Maybe you should accept your own answer just to indicate that the problem is solved...

Comment: i tried but it gives error: You can accept your answer in 2 days